# erro em consulta no mysqli

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Pessoa, como arrumo esse meu codigo, ele esta dando erro:

```
<?php
//IMPRIME TODOS OS VALORES DO BANCO CADASTRO

$servidor = "localhost";
$usuario  = "root";
$senha    = "admin";
$banco    = "cadastro";

//conecta-se ao banco de dados Mysql
$con = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $banco) or die("<script     language='javascript'>alert('Unable to connect to database')</script>"); 

// Verifica se ocorreu algum erro
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
die('Não foi possível conectar-se ao banco de dados: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['buscar'])){
$q = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['consulta']);
$query_Busca = "SELECT * FROM 'equipamento' WHERE 'tombamento' LIKE '%$q%'";
$Busca = $con->query($query_Busca);
$row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_array($Busca);
$totalRows_Busca = $Busca->num_rows;

} else {
$query_Busca = "SELECT * FROM 'equipamento'";
$Busca = $con->query($query_Busca);
$row_Busca = mysqli_fetch_array($Busca);
if (!$check1_res) {
printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
exit();
}
$totalRows_Busca = $Busca->num_rows;
}
?>
```

Os erros que recebo são: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
E ESTE:
Undefined variable: check1_res in C:\wamp\www\cadastro\consulta.php on line 58

Comment: Olá. Pode editar a sua pergunta e acrescentar mais detalhes? Que erro é que dá? Aonde é que dá o erro? Tente explicar melhor o seu problema e não cole apenas o código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando fizer uma consulta e tabela/campo tiver caracteres especiais use:

```
`
```

Aspas simples `'` devem ser somente usadas em valores do tipo texto/character etc

troque as ocorrências:

```
$query_Busca = "SELECT * FROM 'equipamento'";
```

por:

```
$query_Busca = "SELECT * FROM `equipamento`";
```

ou ainda:

```
$query_Busca = "SELECT * FROM equipamento";
```

Ao executar uma consulta lembre de fazer ela exibir o erro do banco de dados assim:

```
$Busca = $con->query($query_Busca) or die($con->error);
```

Comment: Perdeu tu é o cara! Desculpe a falta de detalhes do problema, mas o pouco que você me passou deu pra resolver legal. Agora soh me responde uma coisa: como eu faço para o algoritmo de busca do php ficar em outra pagina eser chamado? Queria fazer isso para ficar mais seguro o Banco de dados. Sabe como faz? se souber edita na sua resposta e adiciona por favor. estou precisando disso também e obrigado por tudo!

Comment: @DarkJontex, pode criar um arquivo separado com funções e usar um [include](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php)/[require](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.require.php) para chama-los em outra página.