# mysqli_result Object ( )

Tags: php, mysqli

passei as ultimas 3 horas tentando achar o erro... talvez seja o sono, mas colocarei meu script complicadíssimo para que alguem me dê uma luz.

```
$query_passaporte = "SELECT num_compra, data_compra, plano, passaporte_paypal FROM paypal WHERE 'empid' = ' ".$_SESSION['empid']." ' AND 'show' ='1' ORDER BY num_compra ASC";

$dados_passaporte = mysqli_query($dbc, $query_passaporte) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

while(list($num_compra, $data_compra, $plano, $passaporte_paypal) = mysqli_fetch_array($dados_passaporte)){

    echo 'nao funciona'.$num_compra. $data_compra. $plano. $passaporte_paypal;} 

    print_r($dados_passaporte); ------> resulta em mysqli_result Object ()
```

ou seja, nao retorna o ECHO.

$dbc está OK.
Na query, uso aspas simples em EMPID e SHOW para nao dar erro de sintaxe (nao sei pq dá erro, outros scripts estao sem aspas)

Foi o primeiro codigo escrito depois que formatei meu windows e pus UBUNTU (se bem que eu tenho certeza que nao tem nada a ver).

Simplismente nao sei o que eu to errando...

Comment: Não use aspas simples `'` em nomes de campos apenas para valores, caso tenha algum nome com caracter especial ou palavra reservador use a crase >>`<<

Comment: Só pra constar: `Object ()` é a saída esperada para `$dados_passaporte`. Seus dados na verdade estão em `mysqli_fetch_array($dados_passaporte)`.

Answer (score 4):

Não use aspas simples `'` em nomes de campos apenas para valores, caso tenha algum nome com caracter especial ou palavra reservada use a crase `` ` `` ("show" é uma [palavra reservada do mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)).

Sua consulta deveria ficar assim:

```
$query_passaporte = "SELECT num_compra, data_compra, plano, passaporte_paypal
FROM paypal WHERE empid = ' ".$_SESSION['empid']." ' 
AND `show` ='1' ORDER BY num_compra ASC";
```

Recomendo o uso de prepared staments para evitar problemas com sql injection.

Comment: @bfavaretto, se souber como fazer um escape na crase avisa ai.

Comment: Estou tentando descobrir. Em comentários funciona se escapar com backslash: `\``. Em posts isso não funciona.

Comment: @bfavaretto, outro dia [respondi](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27636/erro-em-consulta-no-mysqli) praticamente a mesma coisa, isso vale como duplicada?

Comment: Para escapar o backtick: `\`\` \` \`\`` ou `<code>&#96;</code>`.

Comment: Já existem outras perguntas com o mesmo problema em palavras reservadas. Não sei se dá pra considerar duplicata não. Mas merecia uma menção na wiki da tag mysql.

Comment: @bfavaretto, pois é, o contexto da pergunta é diferente mas o erro é o mesmo de parse, pode acontecer de aparecer uma pergunta dessa toda semana. obrigado pela dica do escape :)

Comment: Dependendo do contexto, dá pra usar \\` para escapar o _backtick_. Isso aqui: \`\\`\` vira isso: `\`` (agora, imaginem pra fazer esse comentário o quanto de _escape_ é necessário :) )

Comment: Obrigado @Bacco :)

Comment: Opa, obrigado pela resposta.
não sabia desse lance do SHOW, entao eu vou mudar o nome da coluna. Deve ser isso que tá dando zica.
Agora vc me deixou com outra duvida.
Exatamente onde eu devo tomar cuidado com o SQL injection?

Comment: @Bacco isso funciona em comentários, mas não no corpo do post.